# add condition inside map in mongo script

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, aggregate

This code is working fine. i am joining 2 different document but industryCategoryMapping have one array of object industryCategories . i want to add condition inside array of object.

```
db.brand.aggregate([
   { $lookup:
        {
          from: "industryCategoryMapping",
           as: 'Category',
        let: { entityId: { $toString : '$_id' }},
        pipeline: [
          {
            $match: {
              $expr: {
                $and: [
                  { $eq: ['$type', 'BRAND'] },
                  { $eq: ['$$entityId', '$entityId'] },


                ]
              }
            }
          }

        ]
      }
    }, {
        $project: {
            name: 1, industryCategoryMapping: {
                $map:
                {
                    input: "$Category",
                    as: "each",
                    in: '$$each.industryCategories'
                }
            }
        }
    },

    ])
```

and returns result

```
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dfb18a6dfb32f87deeffa13"),
    "name" : "Gatorade",
    "industryCategoryMapping" : [ 
        [ 
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5dd26e6e34d10718f843caa9"),
                "isDefault" : true,
                "industryCategory" : {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5def644605ea8b5a7c97b48c"),
                    "industryCategory" : {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5def644605ea8b5a7c97b48f")
                    }
                }
            }, 
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5dfb1514dfb32f87deeff97f"),
                "isDefault" : false,
                "industryCategory" : {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5df8990c4d9c000b9c87592a"),
                    "industryCategory" : {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5df8990c4d9c000b9c87592b")
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

But in given Json result industryCategoryMapping array have 2 object i need only isDefault : true type object . Can anyone help me to ignore isDefault : false object from given array.

Comment: I think you want to use `$filter` _instead of_ `$map`. The [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/index.html)  operator lets you specify a condition.

Comment: @ prasad_  you mean to say  $filter:
                {
                    input: "$Category",
                    as: "each",
                    cond: { $eq: [ "$$each.industryCategories.isDefault", 'true' ] }
                }     it is not working

Comment: _true_ without quotes; it is a boolean.

Comment: yes i tried but it is giving same result .

Comment: What does the document structure look like after the _lookup_ stage. Can you run the query _only with the lookup_.

Comment: @PrakashRanjan : Yes in the given stage of this question it would be hard to give a better query, Please update this question to include initial sample docs & also result right after `$lookup` stage. Also why is that `industryCategoryMapping` an array of arrays

Comment: @srinivasy ,@prasad thanks for quick reply . Actually later i found problem in my json . so i did unwind operataion after that it is working as expected . If you observer industry categoryMapping [ [ have 2 open braces that is the reson filter was not working.